# How to deal with answers promoting "hacked" link for premium ressources?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, legal

Let's consider this question: [I need the Demo Content of E-commerce theme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56696629/8620333)

First, it's clearly off topic and should be closed then deleted *(I am pretty sure the meta effect will make this faster)*.

My concern here is about one of the answers showing to the asker how to find *hacked* version of some premium themes for free and giving some links to download two of them.

> [image]

My question is how to deal with this answer? should I **flag it** or simply move on? is it breaking any kind of rule relative to licence or legal stuff?

The answer is probably trivial (yes I should flag it) but I know that the *null theme* trick for wordpress is allowed because most theme are licensed under the GNU General Public License (GPL)

To ask my question differently: is such content allowed within an answer in SO?

This example is probably a bad one since the whole question should not exist but let's suppose such content is within an answer of a question on topic. Someone is basically giving a solution to a programming issue and ending his answer with such *advice*.

---

<sup>PS: don't get suprised with the upvotes, this user is having a voting ring and I already flag it.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd down-vote and delete vote (if you can) and move on.

Moderators are not equipped to deal with things like this or alleged copyright infringements, we don't have the knowledge required - nor should we.

It's up to the copyright owner to contact Stack Overflow to get such things taken down.

Comment: Both the answers imply it's fine to use 'nulled themes'. Whatever the formal legal situation re an individual theme, surely this site doesn't want to give novice programmers the idea that getting round licensing is business as usual.

Comment: There is an answer here which clarifies things nicely: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232041/what-is-nulled-themes